# TinyMCE Spellchecker Service Not Found

Tags: javascript, php, tinymce

```
The spelling service was not found: (spellchecker.php)
```

Trying to integrate spellchecking in TinyMCE Editor but not sure why it gives me this error when click on ABC icon on toolbar

This is how its implemented

```
// Init params
plugins : ['spellchecker],
toolbar: "spellchecker",
spellchecker_rpc_url: 'spellchecker.php',
```

Have also copied the PHP Package for Spell Check from 
[http://download.moxiecode.com/spellcheckers/tinymce_spellchecker_php_4.0.zip][1]

Comment: What does your browser's dev tools tell you about the attempt to access spellchecker.php?  Is it a 400 error?  404 error?  500 error?  Did you place the spellchecker folder in the correct place within TinyMCE's folder structure (in the plugins folder)?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the PSpell driver, you will need to install the following software:

For Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install aspell aspell-en
sudo apt-get install php5-pspell
```

For Centos

```
yum install aspell aspell-en
yum install aspell php5-pspell
```